Sync lesson incompletion status across all courses in LearnDash
I'm trying to implement a lesson syncing feature in my website, which was half successful as shown in this thread:
Sync lesson completion status across all courses in LearnDash
However, while I'm able to sync the completion status of a lesson across all associated courses, I'm unable to implement the same when it comes to syncing the "incomplete" status.
I tried to mirror the code from the answer to the question in the link using appropriate hooks and functions, but the changes are not reflecting:
A custom function to mark all lessons as incomplete
function nzf_sync_lesson_incompletion($user_id, $course_id, $lesson_id){
    if(!empty($lesson_id)){
        $shared_courses = learndash_get_courses_for_step($lesson_id, true);

        //Loop through the shared courses
        foreach ($shared_courses as $shared_course_id => $value){
            // Skip the current course
            if($shared_course_id == $course_id){
                continue;
            }
            // Mark the lesson as incomplete for the user for the concurrent shared course
            
            custom_learndash_mark_lesson_incomplete($shared_course_id, $lesson_id, $user_id);
        }
    }
}
add_action('learndash_mark_incomplete_process', 'nzf_sync_lesson_incompletion', 8, 3);

Edit: I noticed a redundancy in the second function below caused by the 2 loops earlier, which I have also updated in the link mentioned above, and have also modified the code based on the suggestions made by @Anh Tuan Hoang.
A custom function to mark all lessons as incomplete
function custom_learndash_mark_lesson_incomplete($id, $lesson_id, $user_id) {

    // Retrieve the user's progress for the specific course
    $user_progress = learndash_user_get_course_progress($user_id, $id, 'legacy');

    // Check if the user has progress for the lessons in the course and update it
    if (isset($user_progress['lessons'])) {
        // Remove the lesson from progress (mark as incomplete)
        unset($user_progress['lessons'][$lesson_id]);

        // Reduce the number of completed lessons
        $user_progress['completed'] -= 1;

        // Update the last completed lesson ID to the last lesson in the array
        $user_progress['last_id'] = array_key_last($user_progress['lessons']);
    }

    // Retrieve the user's meta and course progress
    $usermeta = get_user_meta($user_id, '_sfwd-course_progress', true);
    $course_progress = $usermeta;

    // Update the progress for the specific course
    if (isset($course_progress[$id])) {
        $course_progress[$id] = learndash_course_item_to_activity_sync($user_id, $id, $user_progress, $course_progress[$id]);
    } else {
        $course_progress[$id] = $user_progress;
    }

    // Save the updated course progress
    update_user_meta($user_id, '_sfwd-course_progress', $course_progress);

    // Mark the lesson as incomplete for the specific course
    learndash_process_mark_incomplete($user_id, $id, $lesson_id);

    // Update group progress if necessary
    learndash_update_group_course_user_progress($id, $user_id);
}


Please note that shared course steps are enabled by default and I'm not going to change that setting after the sunk cost of time trying to implement this sync feature.
